# Connect Google Cloud SQL with Serverless VPC access issue

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, google-appengine-node

I have Google App Engine project and when I try to connect to Google Cloud SQL through Serverless VPC access I got such error

```
ConnectionError: Failed to connect to 11.11.111.1:1433 - unable to verify the first certificate
```

If you have any suggestion that would be great

Here is the code:

```
const createPool = async () => {
  const config = {pool: {}};
  config.user = process.env.DB_USER; // e.g. 'my-db-user'
  config.password = process.env.DB_PASS; // e.g. 'my-db-password'
  config.database = process.env.DB_NAME; // e.g. 'my-database'
  config.server = process.env.DB_PUBLIC_IP;
  config.port = 1433;

  config.connectionTimeout = 60000;
  config.pool.acquireTimeoutMillis = 30000;
  config.pool.min = 1;
  config.pool.createRetryIntervalMillis = 200;

  return await mssql.connect(config);
};
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide details, code, and configuration.

Comment: Note: disable certificate verification for Cloud SQL. The SSL certificate contains the instance name and not the IP address.

Comment: I am trying to connect via Private IP.

Comment: You are leaving out important details in your question.